# Is there a way to write an image to a named pipe in Python, and then read it?

Tags: python, image, computer-vision, named-pipes

```
import os
path = "hello.jpg"
mode = 0o600
import cv2
os.mkfifo(path, mode)
image = cv2.imread("df.jpg")
print(image)
cv2.imwrite(path, image)
cv2.imshow("image", image)
print("FIFO named '% s' is created successfully." % path)
```

1. Creating a named pipe "hello.jpg"
2. Reading image from disk, df.jpg
3. Writing image to named pipe, hello.jpg

This code blocks at `cv2.imwrite(path, image)`.
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: That's what named pipes do. They have a limited buffer size (typically a few kilobyte), then writes block until another process *reads* from the same pipe.

Comment: So the question is, who is *reading* from the pipe that you want to use a named pipe instead of a regular file?

Comment: I want imshow to read from the pipe

Comment: `cv2.imwrite` isn't going to exit until it's finished writing, which isn't going to happen  until *something* starts reading. You're going to have to use two separate threads, at least, to avoid deadlock.

Comment: Okay, so,
```p = subprocess.Popen((cv2.imwrite(path, image)))
p = subprocess.Popen((cv2.imshow("image", image)))
```

should work. But one catch, I don't know how to execute Python commands inside a subprocess.

Comment: You don't; threads aren't subprocesses. Take a look at the `threading` module.

Comment: Processes spawn multiple-threads, which are called sub-processes. I don't see why this won't work. 
I don't want to use threads, because I want to pipe the image to an ML model (Yolov5), and threading with reduce my GPU utilization